# Как воспользоваться методом QStringList::split по двум условиям?

Tags: c++, qt, split

Код:

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
    {
         QString QQ="\\d+(\\.\\d{0,}) \\d+(\\.\\d{0,}) \\d+(\\.\\d{0,})";
         QRegExp rx(QQ);
         if (!checkRegExp(rx))
              return;

         rx.setMinimal(true);
         ui->plainTextEdit_3->clear();
         int pos = 0;
         QString QQQ="";
         while ((pos=rx.indexIn(ui->plainTextEdit_2->toPlainText(),pos)) !=-1)
         {
              QQQ+=rx.cap(0)+"\n";            
              pos+=rx.matchedLength();

         }
         ui->plainTextEdit_3->setPlainText(QQQ);
         QString str=QQQ;
         QStringList list= str.split(" ", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
         //Как в split() можно сделать разбиение сразу и по пробелу и по знаку новой строки?
         QList<float> fl;
         foreach (QString num, list)
         {
              fl.append(num.toFloat());
         }
    }
```

Всё дело в том, что не понимаю, как именно это делается. Пробовал отдельно (из контрола) преобразовать строковый список в список с числами с плавающей точкой (float). Там всё нормально работало. Здесь всё как не работает. Вернее, работает, но не так, как нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете в качестве условия для сплита воспользоваться регуляркой:

```
QRegExp rx("(\\ |\\,|\\.|\\:|\\t)"); //RegEx for ' ' or ',' or '.' or ':' or '\t'
QStringList query = sometext.split(rx);
```

Comment: а какая регулярка будет действовать для пробела и новой строки?
        QRegExp rx("(\\ |\\n)"); - эта?